# Problem importing (and installing) NumPy in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am having major trouble right now trying to use numpy in my jupyter notebook.

When I first tried to simply **"import numpy"**, it came back with the error: **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"**

I then read somewhere that I probably needed to install numpy.

So I did this: **"import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} numpy"**

to which it came back saying: **"EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment"**

Now when it comes to understanding environments or packages or ANYTHING along those lines, I just have no idea what I'm doing. I am in a very beginner course and just following along.

I wish I could understand all of this environment and versioning stuff.

I have no idea where to go from here.

Any insight here would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Edit: I am in fact using Anaconda to launch Jupyter Notebook. Not sure if that means anything to your understanding of my problem or a potential solution.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

For an easy to use graphical user interface to install Python libraries and manage environments, I would recommend [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/). It is well integrated with IPython and Jupyter Notebook in particular.

Comment: Hey @arne thanks very much for your answer. Okay so, I had already been using Anaconda to launch Jupyter notebook. But today, strangely enough, I just used the terminal to open Jupiter notebook (instead of anaconda) by typing "Jupiter notebook" into the terminal. And it fixed my problem! For some reason I'm not having the "ModuleNotFoundError" anymore. Why might that be? Maybe I needed to like download bumpy into anaconda or something? Anyway...I guess I'm just not going to use Anaconda for now...Thanks again mate, Mark

Comment: meant to say *numpy (not bumpy)

Comment: @Mark D. Foti Good to hear that your problem is fixed, even if somewhat mysteriously. Maybe you already have several environments, and you only installed numpy in one of them? As I said, managing environments is easy with the Anaconda GUI, so you could check this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the line bellow, at the notebook:

!pip install numpy

Or you could open up a terminal inside the jupyter notebook and install there, with:

pip install numpy

Another option is to install python3.7 from the anaconda website:

https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

With anaconda a lot of packages come together when you install it. It's better for beginners. Good luck!

Comment: Hey @carolina thanks very much for your answer! Okay so, I had already been using Anaconda to launch Jupyter notebook. But today, strangely enough, I just used the terminal to open Jupyter notebook (instead of anaconda) by typing "Jupyter notebook" into the terminal. And it fixed my problem! For some reason I'm not having the "ModuleNotFoundError" anymore. Why might that be? Maybe I needed to like download numpy into anaconda or something? Anyway...I guess I'm just not going to use Anaconda for now...Thanks again, Mark

Answer (score 0):

In my case, inside Jupyter notebook, you need to change Kernel (Anaconda environment). I thought you changed environment using `conda activate myEnv`, but when launching Jupyter, it defaults to the root environment.
I hope this is in fact true- I am a noob in Anaconda.